# ! Error: docker push exited with Error: 1

Tags: docker, heroku, git-push, docker-image

I'm trying to push my docker image to Heroku but I get this error:
EOF
 !    Error: docker push exited with Error: 1

I tried to retry the push command many times: Heroku container: push web – app calm-bayou-96507
But after one minute (more or less) of pushing the docker image I get the same error.

Here is the logs of my docker command:

```
The push refers to repository [registry.heroku.com/calm-bayou-96507/web]
7686842e236d: Pushing  191.1MB/191.1MB    8db154b68457: Layer already exists    cd4b2eb3c039: Layer already exists    6e73d8f201cb: Pushing  2.603GB/2.603GB    f75f1e7a96e5: Pushing  22.76MB/22.76MB    72d0068e8a69: Pushing   7.69MB/7.69MB    748a464db597: Layer already exists    ebb30ce58669: Pushing  71.38MB/71.38MB    1bd26e8168dc: Waiting    ffc9b21953f4: Waiting      
EOF
 !    Error: docker push exited with Error: 1
```

I'm verifying my connection by speedtest and here is the result:
Speedtest Result:
[image: Speedtest Result]

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you got to give it some times and try again, because Heroku needs to save it or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this, and it has to do with being consistent with the use of `sudo`. As a good last resort:

```
sudo heroku login
sudo heroku container:login
sudo heroku container:push web
```

Not that I logged in with `sudo` and pushed with `sudo`.

When successful, the response will be

```
Your image has been successfully pushed. You can now release it with the 'container:release' command.
```